# How to set up nodebootstrap at Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm using nodebootstrap to start a new nodejs project (http://nodebootstrap.io/) and it's running fine locally. But when I tried to deploy it to heroku, it showed me the follow errors:

```
2016-08-21T05:14:51.789857+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-08-21T05:14:54.116827+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2016-08-21T05:14:56.026808+00:00 app[web.1]: 21 Aug 05:14:56 - NOTICE  [node_modules/nodebootstrap-server/app.js:57] Express server instance listening on port 31254
2016-08-21T05:14:56.104762+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:341
2016-08-21T05:14:56.104766+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2016-08-21T05:14:56.104769+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
2016-08-21T05:14:56.104773+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
2016-08-21T05:14:56.104775+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2016-08-21T05:14:56.104775+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/lib/api/index.js:2:9)
2016-08-21T05:14:56.104776+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
2016-08-21T05:14:56.104777+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
2016-08-21T05:14:56.104777+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
2016-08-21T05:14:56.158230+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-08-21T05:14:56.148890+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Anybody has any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved - I have some unresolved dependency issue that I didn't found when running locally in dev mode